# Why won't my files push to my SFTP server?

Tags: sftp, bzr

I'm having trouble pushing my branch to an SFTP server. I'm following the instructions [here](http://doc.bazaar-vcs.org/bzr.dev/en/mini-tutorial/index.html#publishing-your-branch-with-sftp).

When I push the branch, everything seems to complete successfully. I get the message "Created new branch.", and if I do "bzr push" again, it says "No new revisions to push." But when I ssh to the SFTP server to look at the directory I put my branch in, only the .bzr directory is there. None of my files are there.
Does anyone have any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was [resolved on Launchpad](https://answers.edge.launchpad.net/bzr/+question/82628). Here are some of the answers (taken from the [Launchpad question](https://answers.edge.launchpad.net/bzr/+question/82628)):

From `bzr help push`:

> Description:
>
> The target branch will not have its working tree populated because this is both expensive, and is not supported on remote file systems.
>
> Some smart servers or protocols *may* put the working tree in place in the future.

You might want to follow [this howto](http://wiki.flexion.org/LoggerheadServer.html?BazaarServer) to deploy a complete bzr-loggerhead remote server

Also, and just if you need a working tree in your sftp server you can run `bzr update` as shown in `working-tree`'s help:

If you want to have a working tree on a remote machine that you push to you
can either run `bzr update` in the remote branch after each push, or use some
other method to update the tree during the push. There is an `rspush` plugin
that will update the working tree using rsync as well as doing a push. There
is also a `push-and-update` plugin that automates running `bzr update` via SSH
after each push.

Have a look [here](http://bazaar-vcs.org/BzrTips?highlight=(sshfs)) if your SFTP server does not allow installing bzr or hooks into the repository. For web development, I am using sshfs to keep the public version updated.

For mounting, you will want to use the options `-o idmap=user,workaround=rename` to map the remote user to yourself, and work around an issue with renaming onto an existing file in the SFTP protocol.

### To sum it up into commands

**Prequesites**

```
sudo apt-get install fuse-utils sshfs
```

**Mount dir**

```
mkdir ~/sftp.my-site.org
```

**Mounting**

```
sshfs sftp-username@sftp.my-site.org: ~/sftp.my-site.org -o idmap=user,workaround=rename
```

**Run update**

```
cd ~/sftp.my-site.org; bzr update
```

### Notes

- Replace "sftp-username" with your user name at the SFTP server.
- Replace "sftp.my-site.org" with the SFTP server name.
- Make sure to include the trailing colon : after the server name if using the home directory there.